# UIScrollView can't appear

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview

I got some problem on UIScrollView .. Where the error said "One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined".
Well , I don't understand what is the error means .. 
Here's my code :

```
import UIKit

class LoginView: UIView {

let scroll = UIScrollView()

let topImg        = UIImageView()
let logoImg       = UIImageView()
let emailTf       = UITextField()
let passwordTf    = UITextField()
let personImg     = UIImageView()
let keyImg        = UIImageView()
let loginBtn      = UIButton()
let lineView      = UIView()
let forgotPassLbl = UILabel()

init() {
    super.init(frame: mainScreen)
    backgroundColor = .background
    addSubsView(scroll)
    scroll.setupSubviews([topImg, logoImg, emailTf, passwordTf, personImg, keyImg, loginBtn, lineView, forgotPassLbl])
    setupConstraint()
    setupView()
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("")
}

func setupView() {
    topImg.backgroundColor = .red

    logoImg.image     = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hexagonLogo")


}

func setupConstraint() {
    scroll.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
       make.edges.equalTo(self)
    }
    topImg.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.leading.trailing.equalTo(self)
        make.height.equalTo(screenSize.height / 3)
    }

    logoImg.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.center.equalTo(topImg)
        make.height.equalTo(Margin.m60)
        make.width.equalTo(Margin.m80)
    }

    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
}}
```

Can someone explain to me , how to solve this problem ? :/

Comment: Have you tried googling that error message? It probably is caused because you somewhere defined a class of some given name a second time.

Comment: where do you set constraints for scrollView? and also what `setupSubviews` method do?

Comment: @k8mil , Sorry , i forgot to type the constraint ... I already edit it .. and the problem still same .. , setupSubviews is the same method like addSubsView but i can add more than one view in there.

Comment: @luk2302 , I'm already tried but i dont understand :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you an example that should help you

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
let viewA = UIView()
let viewB = UIView()
let viewC = UIView()

view.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.addSubview(viewA)
scrollView.addSubview(viewB)
scrollView.addSubview(viewC)

scroll.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in // pin scrollView to superViewEdges
    make.edges.equalTo(self)
}

viewA.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.left.right.equalTo(self)
    make.height.equalTo(screenSize.height / 3)
}

viewB.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.equalTo(viewA.snp.bottom)
    make.leading.trailing.equalTo(self)
    make.height.equalTo(screenSize.height / 3)
}

viewC.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.equalTo(viewB.snp.bottom)
    make.leading.trailing.equalTo(self)
    make.height.equalTo(screenSize.height / 3)
    make.bottom.equalTo(scroll) // <- the most important constraint that fill the scrollView 
}
```